# How to perform press multiple keyevents using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-softkeyboard, android-testing, uikeyboard

How to perform  press multiple keyevents using espresso in single action without looping?
For single button press, I can send

```
 onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9));
```

But I don't know to send events to press number 10. 
Can anyone help me on that.
I need to use keyboard actions instead of passing 10 as value to the text file like

```
onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform(typeText("10");
```

Comment: These are all the key codes in android
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent

you can press key code 1 and then key code 0, there is no key code 10

Comment: @liorlis  For that I had to perform each separate actions right?
say 


 onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1));
 onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0));



instead is it possible to do in single interaction ?

Comment: Not as far as i know of - only as a text

Comment: @liorlis if I pass as text, the numbers got set as a string format instead of number format for my case. That's why I wish to feed input through keyboard

Comment: Did not tried it but what happens if you try to :
onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0));

Answer (score 0):

There is not any KEYCODE action to type 10 directly in a single action with Espresso in KeyEvent.java class.

So, you may use two separate Keyboard action to type 10 like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.textView))
    .perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1)
    .perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0)
);
```